# sparse indexes and null values in mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I'm not sure I understand sparse indexes correctly.

I have a sparse unique index on fbId

```
{
    "ns" : "mydb.users",
    "key" : {
        "fbId" : 1
    },
    "name" : "fbId_1",
    "unique" : true,
    "sparse" : true,
    "background" : false,
    "v" : 0
}
```

And I was expecting that would allow me to insert records with null as the fbId, but that throws a duplicate key exception.  It only allows me to insert if the fbId property is removed completely.

Isn't a sparse index supposed to deal with that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sparse indexes do not contain documents that miss indexed field. However, if field exists and has value of `null`, it will still be indexed. So, if absense of the field and its equality to `null` look the same for your application and you want to maintain uniqueness of `fbId`, just don't insert it until you have a value for it.

You need sparse indexes when you have a large number of documents, but only a small portion of them contains some field, and you want to be able to quickly find documents by that field. Creating a normal index would be too expensive, you would just waste precious RAM on indexing documents you're not interested in.

Comment: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, MongoDB provides the option to create partial indexes. Partial indexes offer a superset of the functionality of sparse indexes. 
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/

Comment: Should not be documents stored in index sparse by default? What is the point of having a document, that does not have the field you index? You cannot lookup that document anyway, so why to have it in index?

Answer (score 3):

To ensure maximum performance of the indexes, we may want to omit from indexing those documents NOT containing the field on which you are performing an index. To do this MongoDB has the sparse property that works as follows:

```
db.addresses.ensureIndex( { "secondAddress": 1 }, { sparse: true } );
```

This index will omit all the documents not containing the secondAddress field and when performing a query, those document will never be scanned.

Let me share this article about basic indexes and some of their properties:

Geospatial, Text, Hash indexes and unique and sparse properties: http://mongodbspain.com/en/2014/02/03/mongodb-indexes-part-2-geospatial-2d-2dsphere/

Comment: ensureIndex has been deprecated since MongoDB 3.0, So please use createIndex.

Answer (score 3):

```
{a:1, b:5, c:2}
{a:8, b:15, c:7}
{a:4, b:7}
{a:3, b:10}
```

Let's assume that we wish to create an index on the above documents. Creating index on `a` & `b` will not be a problem. But what if we need to create an index on `c`. The unique constraint will not work for `c` keys because **null value is duplicated** for 2 documents. The solution in this case is to use `sparse` option. This option tells the database to not include the documents which misses the key. The command in concern is `db.collectionName.createIndex({thing:1}, {unique:true, sparse:true})`. The sparse index lets us use less space as well.

> Notice that even if we have a `sparse` index, the database performs all documents scan especially when doing sort. This can be seen in the **winning plan** section of `explain`'s result.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if the index field contains a null value. The index skips over any document that is missing the indexed field. The index is "sparse" because it does not include all documents of a collection.