# Error while setting up compound index

Tags: mongodb

I want to setup compound index on fb_id and ts in my mongoDB. So, I did:

```
PRIMARY> db.sessions.ensureIndex( { fb_id: 1, ts: 1 }, { unique:true } );
```

But I got following error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error index: tracking.sessions.$fb_id_1_ts_1  dup key: { : null, : null }
```

So I checked the indexes in this collection using `db.sessions.getIndexes()`, I got:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "tracking.sessions",
        "name" : "_id_"
    }
]
```

It doesn't look like a duplicate key to me. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB tells you that you have several documents (more than one) with the same `fb_id` and `ts` values, `null` values. In other words, there are documents without `fb_id` and `ts` fields. So, it violates unique constraint across the collection.

As a workaround, you should take a look at [sparse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#sparse-indexes) indexes. Quote from docs:

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the
>   indexed field. Any document that is missing the field is not
>   indexed. The index is “sparse” because of the missing documents when
>   values are missing.

See also:

- [sparse indexes and null values in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608567/sparse-indexes-and-null-values-in-mongo)
- [why DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$notification_1 dup key: { : null }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863561/why-duplicatekeyerror-e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-test-test-notification)

Hope that helps.